# Sharepoint Access Issues - Multiple Users in Org Suddenly Cannot Access Site

Tags: permissions, access

I was hoping I could get some guidance here. I am fairly new to my organization, and have inherited the admin duties of multiple Sharepoint sites that many different users throughout my department utilize. Everything had been fine with these sites so far, until late last week when, all of a sudden, many people began stating they do not have access to the sites anymore. All of them had previously had access to the sites for months, but now they cannot access it anymore. I did not change anything in any of the sites before this. The other thing that is weird is that even when I accept the access request emails that keep coming through, the users come back to me and state that they STILL do not have access to the site. When I check their permissions, it shows that they should have access. Searching through the permissions, nothing is jumping out as odd. This is also true when I look into the unique permissions too. Granted, the amount of groups, users, etc in these sites is a bit ridiculous so it is hard to sift through it all and figure it out, but it looks like everything should be fine. I don't understand why these users would still not have access even when given directly when I accept their requests.

One thing I noticed is that all of the users that have reached out to me about having issues with access are remote employees - They all are on the server using a VPN. Has anyone ever seen something like this happen before? Sudden widespread access issues with no apparent reason? Any insight would be appreciated. I am fairly new to SP and struggling with finding a solution here.

Answer (score 0):

As you confirmed that they should have access the problem will be not on the sharepoint side but on the support infrastructure, in this case problem occurs most probably somewhere during the authentication process.

I have seen something similar and the root cause was that one of the AD servers had an issue with the time sync, it was out of about 5 minutes.

That results in authentication failure (and the event viewer message is misleading as says it is "wrong user name or password")

Run this command from the Front Ends of your farm. 
w32tm /query /source

That will give you the source of the servers are taking their time.

then you can run this command:
w32tm /monitor /domain:yourdomain.com
Check the time sync. for the servers that are used by FEs.

If this is not the cause i would do the following to troubleshoot it further.

1. get in touch with one of the users to have remote trb session.
2. Log in to the front end server and fire up ULS LOG Viewer (open ULS from all FE as you will not know where the Loadbalancer will send the user)
3. Set the ULS viewer to show errors only.
4. Ask user to log in.
5. Review any errors you may see in ULS and Event Viewer on the FrontEnd Servers. 
   Should give you some hints where to look for the problem if you are still stuck you will be at least able to share some more insights into you issue and StackExchange members will be able to help more.